# ruby on rails Errno::EACCES Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - product.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
def show
  name = @product.ProductName
  File.open('product.log', 'a+') do |f2|  
  f2.write Time.new
  f2.write "==>"
end
```

it works fine on my local machine (mac) and this error comes when I deploy on `ubuntu` server (EC2 )

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`File.open("#{Rails.root}/product.log", 'a+') do |f2|` if it is at root, or whatever its path is.

If it still doesn't work try changing permission to 775.

Comment: Still Errno::ENOENT in ProductsController#show
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - #{Rails.root}/product.log

Comment: where is your `product.log` located? I mean the path?

Comment: in the app next to app folder

Comment: Well that is not the correct place to keep it. It is like going away from rails architecture. Either you should have it in logs(if it is updated continuesly by the application) directory or in public directory and have that path included in the command above.